# Submitting HTML form to email, not open mail

Tags: html

Just want it to submit the form information to email. Right now it's opening a browser. Tried to trouble shoot with no luck (terrible google searches for this). Thanks in advance.

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="MAILTO:jordan.max@loop.colum.edu" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <label for="name" class="lbl">Name</label><br />
                            <input id="name" name="name" class="field required" type="text" />

                            <label for="subject" class="lbl">Subject</label><br />
                            <input id="subject" name="subject" class="field required" type="text" />

                            <label for="email" class="lbl">E-mail</label><br />
                            <input id="email" name="email" class="field required" type="text" />

                            <label for="message" class="lbl">Message</label><br />
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="area required" rows="" cols=""></textarea>

                            <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send Message" />

                    </form><!-- end #form1 -->
```

Comment: This is not possible with pure HTML because browsers can't send emails. Browsers will always open your email client if they find a mailto: link (like the one in your form). If you want to send an email without the email client you need a script on your _webserver_ (PHP, Node.js, Java, ...) that sends it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action value is incorrect and should be pointing to a script file on the server and not an email address.

mailto:email@server.com is a URI scheme that loads the user's default mail client.

If your server supports PHP, then do a search for a [PHP Email Form Script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+email+form+script).

Comment: Yeah I was hoping not to use PHP, thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/html-email-form.html 
This would help you. Setting action to "mailto" would let browser invoke the email client to send the form submission to the email address specified.

Comment: Note that this throws security warnings to the user, and also relies on the client machine being able to send emails.